# Referential integrity after disable/enable trigger all

Tags: postgresql

I wonder how to check referential integrity on a table after disabling and reenabling foreign key constraints.

For example :

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE main(id serial, id_delta integer, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# CREATE TABLE delta (id serial, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# ALTER TABLE main ADD CONSTRAINT fk_main_delta FOREIGN KEY (id_delta) REFERENCES delta (id);
ALTER TABLE
```

Let's try to insert a value that do not respect fk_main_delta:

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO main (id_delta) VALUES (1);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "main" violates foreign key constraint "fk_main_delta"
DÉTAIL : Key (id_delta)=(1) is not present in table "delta".
```

=> it logically fails, so I disable FK constraints to force insert:

```
postgres=# ALTER TABLE main DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
postgres=# INSERT INTO main (id_delta) VALUES (1);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# ALTER TABLE main ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

But now, referential integrity is no longer respected.

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM main;
 id | id_delta 
----+----------
  2 |        1
(1 ligne)
```

So is there a way to check integrity afterwards?

Comment: You can _check_ with a simple query (`NOT IN`, `EXISTS` or a left join).  For _validating_, I have no better idea than @a_horse_with_no_name's.

Comment: As the comment I referred to was removed, I have to readd its content: I don't see fixing this any other way than removing the FK and adding it again.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I finally used DROP/CREATE FK constraints, inspired by [this post on Magnus Hagander's blog](http://blog.hagander.net/archives/131-Automatically-dropping-and-creating-constraints.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems that there is no way to check referential integrity after using `DISABLE TRIGGER ALL` / `ENABLE TRIGGER ALL`, I finally used `DROP/CREATE CONSTRAINT` instead.

Inspired by [this post on Magnus Hagander's blog](http://blog.hagander.net/archives/131-Automatically-dropping-and-creating-constraints.html) I used such queries to generate alter commands for removing and creating FK:

```
-- Generate ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "'||nspname||'"."'||relname||'" ADD CONSTRAINT "'||conname||'" '||
pg_get_constraintdef(pg_constraint.oid)||';'
FROM pg_constraint
INNER JOIN pg_class ON conrelid=pg_class.oid
INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid=pg_class.relnamespace
WHERE pg_constraint.contype = 'f'
ORDER BY nspname DESC, relname DESC, conname DESC

-- Generate ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "'||nspname||'"."'||relname||'" DROP CONSTRAINT "'||conname||'";'
FROM pg_constraint
INNER JOIN pg_class ON conrelid=pg_class.oid
INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid=pg_class.relnamespace
WHERE pg_constraint.contype = 'f'
ORDER BY nspname, relname, conname
```

Here is my process:

1. Start Transaction
2. Drop Constraints
3. Do some stuff... (insert, update, whatever...)
4. Create Constraints
5. if it fails then rollback, else Commit Transaction

Answer (score 0):

use `ALTER TABLE ... VALIDATE CONSTRAINT ...`
it does what you want.

Comment: It only works for constraint previously marked as `NOT VALID`, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html  I was wondering about this solution myself, but after trying the bad row is still in the table.